# ajax return success after nth did in SQL

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

i do believe that my code should be fine. but i cannot perform INSERT to the db after i submit the form. can anyone help me?

i have tried it alert ok, but cannot find anyone INSERT value in the db

and most likely, after clicking button, it return to the form again and no alert, even the error one.

this is my html

```
<form>
    <label for="basic">Login Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="loginID" id="loginID" value="" data-mini="true" /></br >
    <label for="basic">Login Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="loginPW" id="loginPW" value="" data-mini="true" /></br >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit ">
</form>
```

this is my js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('form').submit(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: 
            {
                    loginID: $("#loginID").val(),
                    loginPW: $("#loginPW").val()
            },
            url: 'http://mydomain.com/create.php',
            success: function(data){
                alert('Your comment was successfully added');
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('There was an error adding your comment');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

this is my php

```
<?php

include('mysqlConfig.php');

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["loginID"]);
$pw = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["loginPW"]);

$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_user (user_name, password)
VALUES
($id,$pw)";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$link))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{    
    echo "Comment added";
}

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Does your code establish a connection to the database in the mysqlConfig.php file

Comment: yes. i wondering if the network got problem, it should prompt error msg too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you should really switch to PDO (or mysqli) and prepared statements, the problem here is that you are not quoting the variables and as they are strings, you need to quote them:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_user (user_name, password)
      VALUES
        ('$id','$pw')";
```

You should also hash and salt your passwords and never store them as plain text or encrypted.

Comment: @HUNG The `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated so you might run into problems when you update php. The escape function also requires you to set the default character set in order to protect you from sql injections.

Comment: @HUNG What is the output of the php script? You can check that in the network tab of the developers tools or alert `data` in the success function.

Comment: it works and thanks your explainations. it is really helpful. thanks a lot. for the hash part, as i just on the beginning stage, i will do it in the later part, now i just wanna check the basic function works or not. really thanks your help